# Tab issues with Vim while running Tmux

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

When I run Vim inside Tmux, I have to press the tab key two times to get the keypress registered.  I googled around for a while, to no avail, and I don't h ave this problem when I use Vim outside of Tmux.  Is the tab key reserved for something I'm not aware of?

How do I fix this?

Comment: That is not normal; is it only a problem in *Vim* inside *tmux*, or are other programs inside *tmux* affected (e.g. does typing Tab C-d C-d into `xxd` show just a single `09` byte)? What do your *tmux* and *Vim* configuration look like?

Comment: It's not simply a vim problem.  I had the same issue with tab completion in zsh. I haven't really configured anything in tmux besides remapping C-b to C-i.
    `set -g prefix C-i`
    `unbind C-b`
    `bind C-i send-prefix`
edit: sorry about the formatting

Comment: the xxd you mentioned gives me the `Tab0000000: 5461 62                                  Tab`, both inside and outside Tmux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I haven't really configured anything in tmux besides remapping C-b to C-i.
>
> ```
> set -g prefix C-i
> unbind C-b
> bind C-i send-prefix
> ```

While <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>`i`</kbd> are usually distinguished in GUI environment, they generate the same character in tty-based environments like terminal emulators. That character is U+0009, which is the Tab control character. It is represented as the single byte 0x09 in ASCII, UTF-8 and many other encodings. All of the “[C0 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29)” (ASCII 0-31) have keyboard equivalents that combine the Control key with another key (mostly letters, but also some symbols). The Tab control character is generated by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>`i`</kbd>.

You can verify that (at least) *tmux* considers C-i and Tab to be the same by looking at the output of `tmux show-options -g | grep prefix`. You will see it has set your prefix to the key named `Tab`, even though you specified it as `C-i` in your configuration. You can also notice the same canonicalization in the output of `tmux list-keys | grep prefix`.

You may want to pick a different prefix if you do not want to type Tab twice when you want to send one to programs running inside *tmux*.